# Can I query for a path through an XML document instead of just the leaf?

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet, xmllint

When I query an XML document with an XPATH, I only get the matched node(s) as a result. Is there a way to get the matched node(s) together with their parents up until root?

Lets take this very minimal XML example:

```
<myStuff>
  <room name="Kitchen">
    <cupboard name="Yellow Cupboard">
      <shelf name="Upper Shelf">
        <compartment name="Left Compartment">
          <cup name="Shiny cup" />
        </compartment>
      </shelf>
    </cupboard>
  </room>
</myStuff>
```

When I now want to find the `Shiny cup`, I can query (eg. using `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`) for the XPATH `"//cup[@name='Shiny cup']"`, but then I only found it in the document, not in the room itself. Is there a way to find the target the XPATH in the document and then output [an attribute of] all parent nodes to the root?

Like querying for

```
"//cup[@name='Shiny cup']/<for it and each parent thats not myStuff, give @name>"
```

that leads to

```
"Shiny cup",
"Left Compartment",
"Upper Shelf",
"Yellow Cupboard",
"Kitchen"
```

? Since it is not possible to say how many steps there are, I cannot add those statically to the XPATH itself, so the solution seems to have some sort of loop or recursion applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could walk along the `ancestor-or-self` [axis](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp), e.g. using `xmlstarlet`:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//cup[@name="Shiny cup"]' -v 'ancestor-or-self::*/@name'
```

```
Kitchen
Yellow Cupboard
Upper Shelf
Left Compartment
Shiny cup
```

Comment: That is *great*. Is there any way to replace the newline with eg. " > " or is that up for tr/sed magic?

Comment: There are many ways, but all are somewhat cumbersome. E.g. move `ancestor-or-self::*` into `-m`, so `-v` gets executed once per ancestor, then add `-o` to output a fixed string. But simply piping the current output into `| tr '\n' '>'` seems far easier.